# Meaning of 桜のつばみ!

Tags: meaning

So I'm trying to figure out what つばみ means in this sentence? I know 桜 means cherry blossom, and google translate only gave me cherry blossom for the whole sentence. And leaving つば without the み means saliva. Any clarification of this sentence would be appreciated.

Comment: 桜のつぼみ? Or are you talking about [this mascot](https://www.yakult-swallows.co.jp/pages/guide/mascot/283_tsubami)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be 「桜{さくら}のつ**ぼ**み」 if it were to make sense.

「つぼみ」 means "a bud".

So, the phrase means "***the Sakura buds***".  It is not a sentence; It is only a noun phrase.

Comment: It makes more sense now! I misread ぼ as ば. The whole sentence goes:あっ、さくらのつぼみ！
         もうすぐ、桜が咲きます